# Django - Why is this form not valid while it does have all fields?

Tags: django

In my Django project there's a form which has many fields, some of which are FileFields. The `form.is_valid()` method returns False, claiming the FileField fields are empty, but I do upload them, and I know they're being obtained, because when I print the results of both the `request.POST.items()` and `request.FILES.items()` I get this:

```
POST > ('csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'GXS7HcM4MS87EwqsNn0bLyo3CFGLxAEJqGiJHyG0uHRoALzySdVTteXcYvhkojTG')
POST > ('business_type', '0')
POST > ('rfc', 'FOVL950527261')
POST > ('full_name', 'Asdff Asdf Asdf')
POST > ('email', 'asdf@asdf.com')
POST > ('address', 'Sierra Madre Occidental #121 Colonia Lomas de San Francisco')
POST > ('private_phone', '4921055833')
POST > ('cellphone', '4921055833')
POST > ('business_name', 'MUNICIPIO DE JEREZ ZACATECAS')
POST > ('jobs_generated', '123')
POST > ('expected_investment', '123')
POST > ('gender', '0')
POST > ('age', '123')
POST > ('rfc_moral_person', 'FOV950527261')
POST > ('economic_sector', '0')
POST > ('address_street', 'Sierra Madre Occidental #121 Colonia Lom')
POST > ('address_number', '123')
POST > ('address_neighborhood', 'asfd')
POST > ('address_locality', 'Zacatecas')
POST > ('address_between_streets', '')
POST > ('amount_paid', '123')
POST > ('rfc_copy', '')
POST > ('constitutive_act_copy', '')

FILES > ('official_id_copy', <InMemoryUploadedFile: sare_logo_qJg0oPx.png (image/png)>)
FILES > ('business_address_voucher', <InMemoryUploadedFile: sare_logo_qJg0oPx.png (image/png)>)
FILES > ('legal_posession_voucher_copy', <InMemoryUploadedFile: sare_logo_qJg0oPx.png (image/png)>)
```

My form is only this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}

     {{ form|crispy }}

     <div class="border-top">
         <div class="card-body">
             {% block buttons %}
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> {% trans "Enviar" %}
                 </button>
             {% endblock %}
         </div>
     </div>

 </form>
 {{ form.media }}
```

I am correctly getting the files, I think, because I can see them when printing the request.FILES.items(), but the form.is_valid methods says they're missing.

Do you know why could that be, which other thing could be failing?

Comment: How does your view constructs the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how your view function is constructed, make sure to provide the files as parameter to the form in your view function as well:

```py
def yourViewFunction(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # rest of your code
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Exactly, I just saw it, and it was that, I just had a form = FormatUpdateForm(request.POST)